# Can not access SQL Server database information

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server databases. I used a SQL Server database in my website (I add it to my project by add new Item and now it is located in a `App_Data` folder). I can show the needed information of it in a gridview on my localhost but when I upload it on the web hosting server, I can not access it.

What is wrong with it? You can see it here: http://www.kaj.somee.com/SL.aspx

I'm using asp.net 2010 and vb.net

Comment: did you moved App_Data folder as well in your hosting server?

Comment: Yes I did. Perhaps I need some changes in my web.config?

Comment: did you changes the path of that folder as well in web.config?

Comment: No, how should I change it? i have this two informations there? <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ShConnectionStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Javad\Desktop\Sharj\App_Data\ShDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ShDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: Edit your post and include the specific portion of your web.config

Comment: Aha, should I changes C:\Users\Javad\... to that address which the .mdf exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the error. See your excerpt (per comment). Do you really have your app_data folder in path

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Javad\Desktop\Sharj\App_Data\ShDB.‌​mdf
```

Does this path really exist in your hosting machine. I believe NO and in that case Change that path accordingly.